# Running a cmd from java and add sql plus commands

Tags: java, process, sqlplus

I am working at an application with 2 button Run and Commit.
When i press Run, my application run a script in sql plus. The idea is that i want to remain in sql plus and make commit when i press the Commit button. Also i want to see the output of every command. The things are working fine till i press commit. The output is not showing..

My Run button action:

```
package pachet1;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class MyExec {

    public static ProcessBuilder builder;
    public static Process p;
    public static BufferedReader bri;
    public static BufferedReader bre;
    public static   BufferedWriter p_stdin;

    public static void executeScript(String scriptName, String alias, String path, TextArea txtArea) throws IOException
    {

        NtlmPasswordAuthentication userCred = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain",
                "username", "password");
        SmbFile smbFile=new SmbFile("path"  + scriptName, userCred);
        File file = new File("D://" + scriptName);
        try (InputStream in = smbFile.getInputStream()) {
            Files.copy(smbFile.getInputStream(), file.toPath());
        }
        //init shell
        builder = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd" );
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        try {
            p = builder.start();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //System.out.println(e);
        }
        //get stdin of shell
      p_stdin =
          new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

        // execute the desired command (here: ls) n times
        int n=1;

            try {
                //single execution
            p_stdin.write("sqlplus sys/sys@" + alias +" as sysdba");
            p_stdin.newLine();
            p_stdin.flush();
            p_stdin.write("@"+file.toPath());
            p_stdin.newLine();
            p_stdin.flush();
//            p_stdin.write("commit;");
//            p_stdin.newLine();
//            p_stdin.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            //System.out.println(e);
            }


        // finally close the shell by execution exit command
        try {
            p_stdin.write("");
            p_stdin.newLine();
            p_stdin.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    // write stdout of shell (=output of all commands)
        String line;
       bri = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
               bre = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
              while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
                txtArea.appendText(line + "\n");
                  System.out.println(line + "\n");
              }
              //bri.close();
              while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
               txtArea.appendText(line + "\n");
                  System.out.println(line + "\n");

              }
              //bre.close();
              System.out.println("Done.");



    }
}
```

My commit button action:

```
 Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {

            try {
                MyExec.p_stdin.write("commit");
                MyExec.p_stdin.newLine();
                MyExec.p_stdin.flush();
                MyExec.p_stdin.write("exit");
                MyExec.p_stdin.newLine();
                MyExec.p_stdin.flush();
                //txtArea.appendText("Commit complete.");
                 String line;
                    MyExec.bri = new BufferedReader
                            (new InputStreamReader(MyExec.p.getInputStream()));
                           MyExec.bre = new BufferedReader
                            (new InputStreamReader(MyExec.p.getErrorStream()));
                          while ((line = MyExec.bri.readLine()) != null) {
                            txtArea.appendText(line + "\n");
                              System.out.println(line + "\n");
                          }
                          MyExec.bri.close();
                          while ((line = MyExec.bre.readLine()) != null) {
                           txtArea.appendText(line + "\n");
                              System.out.println(line + "\n");

                          }
                          MyExec.bri.close();
                          System.out.println("Done.");

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

         }
    });

    public void commit(ActionEvent e)
    {     

    t1.start();

    }
```

So i need in that thread to get the process output from run button and continues to display it, but it's not working..

Comment: Is that your real password ? please remove it.

Comment: @AlexPoole it doesn't matter why i use sys, yes i am running scripts that perform DBA, my problem is why i cant get the reader from executeScript and use it for the commit button..

Comment: To execute an external command, you cannot pass the command to the standard input of a `cmd.exe` process.  Instead, pass the command itself to a ProcessBuilder:  `new ProcessBuilder("sqlplus", "sys/sys@" + alias, "as", "sysdba", "@" + file)`

Comment: @VGR the idea is that i wany to pass the commands separatelly. When i press a button i need to execute s file and when i press the second i need to commit. I need to do this on the same session.